# How to use the order_by defined on the relationship in SQLAlchemy and contains_eager?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The [Zen of Joined Eager Loading](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html#the-zen-of-joined-eager-loading) docs recommends using `contains_eager()` if we want to keep the relationship order defined in the model.

"If we wanted to use just one JOIN for collection loading as well as ordering, we use the contains_eager() option, described in Routing Explicit Joins/Statements into Eagerly Loaded Collections below."

But the following example seems to behave otherwise. I must be missing something, but unsure what.

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent"

    parent_id = Column(types.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(types.String(200), nullable=False)


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"

    order = Column(types.Integer, default=0)
    name = Column(types.String(200))

    parent_id = Column(types.Integer, ForeignKey(Parent.parent_id))
    parent = relationship(
        Parent,
        backref=backref(
            "children",
            cascade="all,delete",
            order_by="Child.order",
        ),
    )
```

```py
query = session.query(Parent).options(
    contains_eager(Parent.children)
).filter(Parent.parent_id == 99).filter(Child.name == "foo")
```

Generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT parent.parent_id, parent.name,
       child.order, child.name,
FROM parent, child
WHERE parent.parent_id = 99 AND parent.name = 'foo'
```

For some reason,

```
ORDER BY child.order
```

is missing, even though it's defined in the `relationship()`. Any hints?

It works fine if the order_by is specified at query time, but I want to avoid writing the same ordering criteria multiple times.

Comment: "Contains eager" tells SQLA "I'll handle the join etc., just fill the relationship from the results". You have not joined or used `order_by`, so they do not appear in the query.

Comment: By joined I mean used an explicit JOIN.

Comment: Even if I stick an `.join(Child)` before `.options()` in the query, nothing changes.

Comment: You must provide the entire query, including order by, if you inform SQLA that you're forming the query yourself.

Comment: I guess you mean adding the `.order_by()` in the query. That works, but the ordering would be defined in 2 places. Isn't there any way to make SQLA read the query from the mapping?

Comment: how about using  "ordering_list", you can use this to do this in the model you define rather than the query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is correct, and it refers to the fact that if using most out-of-the box eager loading methods, the query is modified and might not be optimal.

The suggestion is then to use `contains_eager` where:

1) the user is responsible for constructing the correct query (including joins, filters, ordering etc)

2) by using `contains_eager` the user *hints* SA that the specified relationship is *included* in the query.

---

The way to load relationship eagerly would be to use `joinedload`:

```
q_joined = (
    session
    .query(Parent)
    .options(joinedload(Parent.children))
    .filter(Parent.parent_id == parent_id)
)
```

But you cannot apply these additional filters in this case.

Using the `contains_eager` you would do:

```
q_manual = (
    session
    .query(Parent)
    .join(Child)  # MUST HAVE THIS
    .options(contains_eager(Parent.children))
    .filter(Parent.parent_id == 99)
    # .filter(Child.name == "foo")  # you can add this, but you are "tricking" SA into believing that only these 'Child' are part of the Parent.children relationship.
    .order_by(Parent.parent_id, Child.order)  # JUST ADD THIS to solve the ordering
)
```